# Reference to variable name in a time-series object in R

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose I define a time-series object in R with three columns (variables) denoted X,Y,Z and put them collectively in a time series object myTS. Is there any way I can pick out X by myTS$X, myTS$Y and myTS$Z ? If not, any suggestion for a package with this functionality?

Minimal example:

```
Y <- c(11,21,31,41)
X <- c(12,22,32,42)
Z <- c(13,23,33,43)
data <- cbind(Y,X,Z)
myTS <- ts(data,frequency=1,start=c(1960, 1), end=c(1963,1))
```

myTS$Y or myTS[Y] doesn't work.

Thanks,
Lasse

Comment: `myTS[,"Y"]`. Look at the output of `str(myTS)`.

Comment: If its ok to use the `"zoo"` class then it will work:  `library(zoo); z <- as.zoo(myTS); z$Y`

Comment: The suggestion to use `unclass()` was posted before as a comment, but now it seems to be gone. While `xts` and `zoo` make working with time series easier than the base `ts`, you can extract in this case the values of column `Y`with `y <- unclass(myTS)[,"Y"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Given a ts object with multiple columns, you can retrieve the names of the variables via `colnames`, for example:

```
colnames(myTS)
## [1] "Y" "X" "Z"
```

You can then access that variable/column by character name:

```
myTS[,"Y"]
## Time Series:
## Start = 1960 
## End = 1963 
## Frequency = 1 
## [1] 11 21 31 41
```